# DateTime.Ticks, DateTime.Equals and timezones

Tags: c#, datetime, date

How come the following code (in C#) returns false :

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
d.Ticks == d.ToUniversalTime().Ticks; // false
```

I'd expect the ticks of a DateTime to be based on UTC time.
The MSDN page on [DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) mentions says

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001, which represents DateTime.MinValue. It does not include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.

Midnight on January first, 0001 .. in which timezone ?

Why would DateTime.Ticks be timezone dependant ?

I guess that the fact that the Ticks are different is why the following code also returns false

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
d == d.ToUniversalTime(); // false
```

The MSDN doc on [DateTime.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5t802s.aspx) mentions

> t1 and t2 are equal if their Ticks property values are equal. Their Kind property values are not considered in the test for equality.

My expectation was that DateTime.Ticks would be equal, no matter the timezone.

I'd expect two moments in time to be equal no matter on what timezone they happened. Are my expectations wrong ?

Comment: Note that you can use DateTimeOffset (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.op_equality.aspx) which compares the moment in time when comparing two instances.

Comment: @ChrisShaffer Thanks, I think that this is what I should be using since what I'm looking for is exact moments in time and not actual "dates".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/fde7e5b0-e2b9-4d3b-8a63-c2ae75e316d8

> DateTime.Ticks is documented as "number of 100-nanosecond intervals
>   that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001".  That is
>   1-Jan-0001 local time.  If you convert your DateTime to UTC, Ticks
>   will then be number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed
>   since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 UTC.  Potentially different
>   that 1-Jan-0001 local time, ergo the two Ticks values will be
>   different.

Answer (score 2):

Your current Datetime (unless you live in the one specific time zone - GMT) is offset from the UTC time by x hours, so DateTime.Now might put you at 4 AM while Datetime.Now.ToUniversalTime() could be at 11 PM depending on your current time zone.

The Ticks are calculated ***after*** the conversion from your time zone to universal time, so the only time they should be equal is if you live in the GMT time zone.

Put more simply, the number of ticks between 1/1/2011 8:00 AM is not the same as the number of ticks since 1/1/2011 11:00 PM.  In your code, the date is being converted to the universal date, and then ticks being calulated on the right side of the equation, but it's just using your local date to get the difference on the left, hence, they're != each other.

Comment: I assume the two would be equal because they represent the exact same moment in time. I didn't expect that a change in the frame of reference would change the equality.

Comment: @GuiSim - That first line shouldn't have been in my answer.  When I re-read it, it sounded like I was being condescending.  Sorry about that.  I didn't mean to be.  I'm just awful at written communication.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now` is determined based on your time zone offset which means it won't be the same as universal time unless your offset is zero.  It wouldn't make sense to convert `DateTime.Now` to ticks in two different time zones and get the same result - they are the same absolute time (UTC), but not the same relative time (using the time zone offset).